# Does Kafka preserve message order during rebalancing?

Tags: apache-kafka

In our application, messages belonging to the same customer need to be processed in order. To achieve this, I set the message's key to the customer id. In the application, each consumer is backed by a single thread as well.

Now we see cases where for some reason (which I am trying to find) the message order is broken. The question here is: does Kafka preserve message order during rebalancing? That is, when partitions are re-assigned (typically when a node goes down or reconnects to the cluster), does Kafka wait for messages (which were already polled, and most likely being processed as well, by an active customer) to be processed and acknowledged before moving the partition from one consumer to the other?

Comment: How does your consumer handle offset commits? If you let it happen automatically, it's possible you're processing data more than once, but not necessarily "out of order" with respect to the offsets

Comment: Commits are indeed happening in the background; that is, default kafka client configuration, no manual ack in the application. We have an idempotent implementation, so more than once should be fine, but we are seeing cases in which order is not preserved, and I'm trying to find the root cause of that.

Comment: How are you checking the order , though? Are you actively printing record offsets, and perhaps consumer thread id? (maybe multiple threads are printing logs, and thread logs are overlapping with each other)

Comment: We are getting constraint violations in the SQL database which should not happen if messages were processed in order. Also logs confirmed wrong processing order. The messages are in the correct order in the topic, we confirmed that already.

That said, I am mainly thinking aloud here, as I have no reason to believe/blame that Kafka is wrong; mainly asking questions to understand if there are known gotcha's or flows (such as during re-assignment of partitions) during which Kafka might not (be able to) respect the order. I'm more or less in the dark right now, hence my generic question.

Comment: Yes, a group rebalance can re-assign partitions, and it can seek backwards to the last committed offset (let's say an offset commit failed, or you aren't manually committing, or ack-ing as you say, your offsets, and letting it happen automatically, with/without error handling). In those cases, then yes, events can be delivered more than once, but they will not be "out of order" from one consumed/assigned partition. In other words, the other case to consider, is that you have events across multiple partitions that should be "ordered", but are not since Kafka cannot order across partitions.

Comment: Regarding SQL database, are you not using JDBC Sink connector? You've written a consumer manually?

Answer (score 0):

> each consumer is backed by a single thread

This means every partition will be consumed in order, for each partition (by customer id).

> does Kafka preserve message order during rebalancing

Rebalancing does not affect message order on the broker; offsets are immutable.

What does change, is where your consumer group will reset its offset to, after a rebalance. If you have not disabled auto offset commits, then it doesn't matter if you have producer idempotence and consumer read-isolation, because out of 10 messages, if you process 5, but only 3 is auto-committed and you rebalance, then you re-consume offsets 4 and 5 before processing 6+. You fix this by ensuring a commit for every offset, or do an external database lookup for every record to ensure it's not been processed already.